# C# winform Clear mouse event arg

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent

// Is it possible to create 1 mouse even for 2 text box?

Lets say i have 2 text boxes, (TxtBox1, TxtBox2)

what i want is 1 Clear function that will clear only the text button which was clicked, without the need to create 2 clear functions for each one : TxtBox1.Clear(); TxtBox1.Clear();

Here is another explanation of what i thought C# would support :

```
    private void Clear(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Clear();
              }
```

Comment: It is not really clear what you are after; do you have one button and you want to clear two text boxes with the same button? If so how do you differenciate?

Comment: Or do you have two buttons and you want each to clear a textbox without writing two handlers?

Comment: i have 2 text box, i wanna clear only the the one who i'm clicking on (clear the default text )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sender` is the UI element that was clicked so the following should work:

```
private void TextBoxOnClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var theTextBox = sender as TextBox;
    if (theTextBox != null)
    {
        theTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

The `as` and check for null is just defensive programming. If you're sure that this will only ever be called from a TextBox then you can do a direct cast.

Then you need to add this to the click event handler for each text box:

```
TxtBox1.OnClick += TextBoxOnClick;
TxtBox2.OnClick += TextBoxOnClick;
```

etc. for all your text boxes.

Comment: If you want to avoid the downcasting, you can inherit the TextBox and add this feature onto the box itself.